# Is “come September” a kind of inversion?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

From NPR, transcript [here](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=318246129).

> Michelle Scott is reading from the Common Core math standards for
>   fifth-graders. She'll be teaching fifth next year, along with John
>   Gries. And together, they're writing—and rewriting—lessons
>   they'll need **come September**.

For the last sentence, did he want to say, “they're re-writing lessons they'll need if September comes”? He inverted the last part, put the verb “come” in the front and omitted “if”, right?

As far as I could determine, it seems only “if” with subjunctive voice could be used in this way. I don't think it's a subjunctive voice. In my impression, the subjunctive voice stands for those occasions when you're not sure whether it will happen or not, such as “If it were to rain, I'd pick you up.”

September will come sooner or later (it's not in limbo), so I'm wondering how to explain the sentence.

Comment: It's not *if*; it's *when*. This *come* might be a little unfamiliar, but it's common enough. It's a preposition: [come](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/come?q=come) (prep.) "When a specified time is reached or event happens: *'I don’t think that they’ll be far away from honours come the new season'*"

Comment: The New Oxford American Dictionary (Oxford University Press, 2020) considers "come" a preposition: "when a specified time is reached or event happens". Also compare [the definition as a phrase in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/come-july-next-year-the-next-day-etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When *come* used as a preposition this way, it means *at that time.*

> [come (prep)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come_53) - *at a particular time in the future or when a particular event happens.*

Note that it's an informal way to say that as MM describes.

You may simply paraphrase that sentence in - *lessons they'll need **in** September or when September comes.*

Answer (score 5):

One could say that *come* can be used in many idioms:

- **come *month*, come *season*** = when $Date$ comes aka when it becomes $Date$ (examples: come September, come Summer. So the sentence can be interpreted as, "And together, they're writing - and re-writing - lessons they'll need **when it becomes September**."
- **come hell or high water** = no matter what aka not matter what it takes aka no matter what effort is required (Movie scenes: Tough and Rough Guy: "Don't worry, I'm gonna (going to) get you outta (out of) here *come hell or high water* (no matter what).
- **come rain or shine** = same as come hell or high water but less emphatic (due to lack of "curse word") (Movie scene: Strong guy yet gentleman: "I'll deliver this letter for you Miss, come rain or shine."
- Here is how to research the basic question via a search engine: - [grammar meaning "come January" OR "come February" OR "come March" OR "come April" OR "come May" OR "come June" OR "come July" OR "come August" OR "come September" OR "come October" OR "come November" OR "come December"](https://www.google.com/search?q=grammar+meaning+%22come+January%22+OR+%22come+February%22+OR+%22come+March%22+OR+%22come+April%22+OR+%22come+May%22+OR+%22come+June%22+OR+%22come+July%22+OR+%22come+August%22+OR+%22come+September%22+OR+%22come+October%22+OR+%22come+November%22+OR+%22come+December%22)

Regarding the grammatical function, some say it's the "temporal subjunctive" while others suggest it can be considered a preposition.

- Here is how to look deeper into the subjunctive vs. preposition arguments:  [subjuntive preposition "come January" OR "come February" OR "come March" OR "come April" OR "come May" OR "come June" OR "come July" OR "come August" OR "come September" OR "come October" OR "come November" OR "come December"](https://www.google.com/search?q=subjunctive+preposition+grammar+meaning+%22come+January%22+OR+%22come+February%22+OR+%22come+March%22+OR+%22come+April%22+OR+%22come+May%22+OR+%22come+June%22+OR+%22come+July%22+OR+%22come+August%22+OR+%22come+September%22+OR+%22come+October%22+OR+%22come+November%22+OR+%22come+December%22)

Comment: I'm impressed by your searching method!

Comment: _c.f.: [Come Rain or Come Shine](http://youtu.be/ij3SL4P4zYQ)._